# Can't change Placeholder text color

Tags: forms, placeholder

i'm working on this website and i want to change the form's "placeholder" text **from grey to white. (the one one the left) and from grey to black (the one on the right)**. But i can't find a solution. How can i solve it?

```
<form method="POST" name="contactform" action="contact-form-handler.php"> 
                <select name="dropdown">
                  <option value="Ich wünsche eine Rohbaubesichtigung">Ich wünsche eine Rohbaubesichtigung</option>
                  <option value="Ich wünsche eine Präsentation über AQUILA bei mir im Hause">Ich wünsche eine Präsentation über AQUILA bei mir im Hause</option>        
                </select>   
                <p>
                
                <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name und Vorname" class="ph">
                </p>
                <p>
                
                <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="E-Mail" class="ph"> <br>
                </p>
                <p>
                
                <input type="text" name="betreff" placeholder="Betreff" class="ph"> <br>
                </p>
                <p>
                
                <textarea name="message" placeholder="Nachricht"></textarea>
                </p>
                <input type="submit" value="Senden"><br>
                <img id="spazio_pic" src="img/logo_form_left.png" alt="" class="" width="100%" height="50" align="left" />
                </form>
```